# FBX file to video conversion

Tags: export, video

I have all my action files in .fbx format. Usually i import to Powerpoint and Export as Video with Green background so that i can remove the ChromaKey in my video editor to have the animation.

Please let me know if there is a way to import the FBX file and then take an output video or any workflow in BLENDER that will let me take my character do animation in my videos.

Comment: Adding green to take it out later makes no sense to me, when you can generate a proper alpha channel and have no degradation on the image. Import your scene and render in blender as an image sequence with alpha, and composite later. Or composite directly in blender.

Comment: The fact that he imports an .fbx into PPT should already give you shivers down your spine...

Comment: Lol... Friend, very new to 3d world.  This is my work flow
1) Create a character in MakeHuman software.
2) Export as .obj file after modelling. It gives you 1 .obj, 1.mtl and a texture folder. Zip them all.
3) import that zip file in to mixamo.com. You can animate the characters in minutes
4) Download any animation as .fbx file with skin
5) Import that .fbx file to Office 365 PowerPoint
6) File export as video from Powerpoint
https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCNT7WQMdlgFnevMERzSrt_Q

With step 5 got broken, I am seeking help from Blender to continue this workflow.